# How to pass props through this.props.children() not this.props.children

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to pass all my props through the gatsby layout. For example:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

export default class ExampleLayout extends Component {
  render() {
    const { data } = this.props;
    return <div>{this.props.children(data)}</div>; // --> this does not work, but I want to do something like this
  }
}
```

Something to note here is that this is calling `this.props.children()` as a function not a non-function call `this.props.children`. I tried to do the way with the non-function call recommended on other post, but could not get it to work.

Comment: `<div {...data}></div>;` do you mean passing data to children as props? OR I think you probably meant this: https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/2982#issuecomment-72340814

Comment: Everything you need is here: 
https://zhenyong.github.io/react/docs/transferring-props.html

Comment: No I dont think we are talking about the same thing. Gatsby render the pages through the layout. So I wanted some way to pass through the props to any page rendered through. So I am not talking about doing something like `<div><MyChildComp props={...props}/></div>`, but better when you use or call this.props.children() how . can I make sure all those children get the props dynamically

Comment: You can only call `children()` if children is a function. https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#functions-as-children

Comment: Why your example doesn't work? What the error is? Doesn't it work: `<div>{() => this.props.children(data)}</div>`?

Comment: You have to pass this.props.children() between the two divs or else the gatsby pages won't load, I have no control over that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use React.Children.map or React.Children.forEach and iterate through all of the direct children of your component and pass them down your props.
eg:

```
import React, { Component, Children } from 'react';

export default class ExampleLayout extends Component {
  render() {
    const { data } = this.props;
    const children = this.props.children()
    {Children.map(children, child => React.cloneElement(child, { ...data}))}
  }
}
```

Comment: So like I said this will actually break the layout , because this is not invoking `this.props.children`. In gatsby you have to invoke `this.props.children()` as a function. So my attempt to fix this was to just do `children()` in the map, but that did not work. As I said I already tried this, but I should have added in an example so it would not confuse.

Comment: If you mean that you get your children from Gatsby by calling this.props.children() and then you need to render them you can just pass that as the children argument to the React.Children.map instead of the props.children like so : {Children.map(this.props.children(), child => React.cloneElement(child, { ...data}))}

Comment: I already tried that as well but the data wasn't passed through as props. I'm not sure if this is because Gatsby does something different or not. If that should work then change your answer to that and I'll accept it, but make sure it works on your end.

Comment: Did you try to pass the data to the children function as prop object :
this.props.children({data}) as opposed to your example this.props.children(data) ?

Comment: Yes tried {...data} and {data}. It may just be gatsby blocking it, im not sure.

Comment: looking at the source code it looks to see if you are passing props to this function if so it renders them if not it renders the default props of the layout so in your case you probably want to pass your props in addition to the default ones like so:
this.props.children({...this.props, ...data})

Comment: Yeah to me that should work, but it's not for me so I'm not sure what is going wrong, no errors just not working either. So if I log out this.props on my index page there is no data prop passed down. Could be something I'm doing wrong somewhere, anyway thank you for your time and effort for helping me.

Comment: i hope you figure it out . Here is the source code i was refering to if that helps you to get some more clarity later on : https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/blob/master/packages/gatsby/cache-dir/root.js#L165